# How to Integration Drupal 7x And Moodle 2x?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, moodle

Hello guys Currently i am working on Drupal 7x And Moodle 2x integration but i can't integrated . 
I face the **ERROR: Problems trying to get index of users!** .

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/project1/auth/drupalservices/REST-API.php on line 201
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/project1/auth/drupalservices/REST-API.php on line 202

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/project1/auth/drupalservices/REST-API.php on line 202
RemoteAPI Object
(
    [gateway] => http://localhost
    [endpoint] => /testproject
    [status] => 1
    [session] => 
    [sessid] => 
)
ERROR: Problems trying to get index of users!
```

For Drupal And Moodle integration i fallow this link on git hub.
For Drupal:- https://github.com/cannod/moodle-drupalservices/wiki/Installation-Drupal-Side

For Moodle :-  https://github.com/cannod/moodle-drupalservices/wiki/Installation-Moodle-Side

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I do that :) I integrated drupal7x and moodle2x successfully . Guys if you have stock in integration of any point you ask mi ! through the comment .

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to integrate Drupal with Moodle, you can check [Drupal commerce Moodle](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_moodle) integration. It integrates Drupal commerce with Moodle.

Maybe that can help.

Comment: Thanks For reapply ! But I want Integrate both for User role like if i login on Drupal its also login on moodle. Both login interface are same !